# Copy columns in one data frame into another over multiple rows

Tags: r

I have two data frames of unequal length, A and B. I want to copy the columns of A into B based on two columns. However, since the data frames are not equal length, I want to have multiple copies of the same row wherever a match occurs. For example:

*A*

```
Team       Season     stat1     stat2     stat3
Maryland     2002      23.0      2.54      3.43
Duke         2002      32.1      2.11      2.56
Siena        2002      21.5      3.11      2.11
```

*B*

```
Team         Season
Maryland     2002
Siena        2002
Maryland     2002
Duke         2002
```

*Final*

```
Team     Season     stat1     stat2     stat3
Maryland   2002      23.0      2.54      3.43
Siena      2002      21.5      3.11      2.11
Maryland   2002      23.0      3.11      3.43
Duke       2002      32.1      2.11      2.56
```

So, I want to copy stat1, stat2, and stat3 from A into B based on the character strings in Team and Season. Note that Maryland shows up more than once, so I want to copy stat1, stat2, and stat3 into BOTH rows. Also, for length sake, I only included data from the same season 2002, but I want to be able to match based on both the Team and Season. I have tried using the merge function, but it does not seem to copy into multiple rows.

*Note* This is my first post on here, so forgive me for not having the best formatting. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming B = data_b and A = data_a

```
final<-merge(data_b,data_a,by=c("Team","Season"),all.x=TRUE)
```

Comment: Is there a way to keep the original order of data frame B? Your code works, but the rows are returned in alphabetical order. I want to keep the original order of B because each group of two rows is a tournament game (Team1 vs Team2)

Comment: data_b<-as.data.table(data_b), data_a<-as.data.table(data_a),final<-merge(data_b,data_a,by=c("Team","Season"),all.x=TRUE,sort=FALSE)

Answer (score 0):

Easy peasy. Use the merge function. In this case it would be:
merge(A, B, by = c('Team','Season'), all.Y = TRUE)